# How to load RSA public and private key from memory

Tags: c, openssl, rsa

I need to hard code my RSA private/public key in my app, the key is actually
a file in PEM format, how can I load it from memory by calling OpenSSL routines?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use OpenSSL's BIO functions to allow reading from a memory location:

```
BIO *key_bio;
RSA *key;
char private_key_data[] = // your private key

key_bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(private_key_data, -1);
key = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(key_bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Run `man 3 bio`, `man 3 BIO_new_mem_buf`, and `man 3 pem` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try `EVP_PKEY *PEM_read_PrivateKey(FILE *fp, EVP_PKEY **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u);`

Comment: Needs a massive amount of expansion for this answer, if it is an answer, to be usable. Sadly, you can't even point OP at the man page because the man page is a cryptic mess.